A French Con Movie probably between 1975 - 1985
I'm looking for a french con movie. I think it was made in between late 70s and early 80s. There is an old man and a middle aged woman, who are partners and design cons to rob single, white, middle aged men. The old guy starts conversations with the victims and learns info about them. Then the woman flirts with that victims and act like as if she impressed them. Usually they find these victims at luxury hotels and business conferences. When they go up to the victim's hotel room, the woman puts a sleeping pill to his drink and robs him. One of these cons, the woman fells in love with a man and gives up the cons. She decides to live with this guy and they are seperated with the old man. 
I remember they had an phone conversation. She asked what's he doing, and he replied nothing much, I wander around, be in public places, eating in different places etc. He asked as if she would like to continue the cons but she said no to that. After a while this guy who the woman fells in love with, realizes that they're robbers and then he holds the woman demanding money from the old guy. The old guy prepares the money and try to save her from him. 
All filming locations were in Europe. I remember Brussels , Paris , Monaco, Swiss Alps, etc. The woman was about 35 aged - tall (above 1.70m) - brown medium size haired and normal weight. The old man was short, bald and calm.

A lot of it sounds like Chabrol's The Swindle, but the year is way off (1997).

@Walt Time for you to answer it then

Sure, no problem.

You're describing Claude Chabrol's The Swindle with Isabelle Huppert and   Michel Serrault.

Betty and Victor are a pair of scam artists. One day Betty brings in Maurice, a treasurer of a multinational company. Maurice is due to transfer 5 millions francs out of Switzerland, and Betty is convinced he plans to steal that money. On whose side is Betty - Victor's, Maurice's or only her own?

Everything fits the bill: The plot, the locations and the con artists' method and physical appearance. Only the year is off (it's from 1997). Here's the trailer:



